# How to rewrite an url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to encode my website url(Url Masking).

For example if my original url is

```
http://domain-name/sample/example/test.php
```

I want it display url as

```
http://domain-name/test
```

how can i mask website address?

Comment: This has nothing to do with encoding or masking. This is about rewriting. Also it has nothing to do with php, please remove that tag from the question.

Comment: There are endless examples here on SO giving detailed examples on how to implement such rewriting rules as you are looking for. None of all those answers helped you to get your task done? _Why not?_ You need to tell us what you tried yourself and where you got stuck. how else do you expect us to help? Or are you just looking for someone to do your work for you? Sorry, SO is _not_ a free coding service...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general HTACCESS does not change the URL or mask the URL. You will have to rewrite the URL to the pattern you like and add instruction in HTACCESS to make the URLs patterns understandable by server

For more details about how to work with rewriting URL and HTACCESS [check this website](https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners)

Rewriting the URL otherwise named as `Friendly URL`

I assume in your code (HTML or PHP) you probably will have

```
<a href="http://domain-name/sample/example/test.php">link</a>
```

which should be changed to

```
<a href="http://domain-name/test">link</a>
```

as part of rewriting the URL where `http://domain-name/test` URL is like alias

Now you should write instruction in `.htaccess` file to redirect the URL alias to actual URL

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule ^test$ /sample/example/test.php [L] # Handle requests for "test"
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. It should have been a comment.

Comment: @arkascha Oh.. that was sweet.. you probably went through my initial brief answer.. check now

Comment: Much better now, thanks for adding a specific answer. Two enhancement suggestions: 1. change the rule so that the whole hierarchy below that entry point gets rewritten since that most likely is what the OP is looking for and 2. make the rule robust to be used not only in dynamic configuration files but likewise in the real http servers host configuration and point out why that host configuration should be preferred over dynamic configuration files.